# Flutter: Google Map Plugin how to draw a line between two coordinates inside map

Tags: dart, flutter, dart-pub, flutter-dependencies

How to show multiple markers with fit zoom level in map, I am using below plugin for develop a map?

https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/google_maps_flutter

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53171531/how-to-add-polyline-on-google-maps-flutter-plugin)

Polyline is currently (2019-01-27) not available in the [official google maps flutter plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53171531/how-to-add-polyline-on-google-maps-flutter-plugin). However, there are two pull requests which have added this functionality:

- [1121](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/1121)
- [941](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/941)

Pull request 1121 has example code on how to use the Polyline functionality.