# Add custom roads google maps + navigation

Tags: android, google-maps, flutter

I'm making a navigation app using flutter + google maps for a large estate and there are some roads inside the estate that doesn't appear in google maps but actually exist. I want to know how to add custom roads to google maps and show routes / distance between two points with my added custom roads

I did some researches about this and I found that [KML](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/kml) can use to add custom locations/paths to the map. But at this moment [google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter) doesn't support kms layers (maps android sdk support, but not flutter plugin). Is there a way around to implement KML in flutter without official support?

And just to be sure, when I added KML data to my map somehow, when user using navigation feature in my app, does user see the normal navigation route (like I used google maps app, no custom roads) or do I get path using my custom routes?

Thanks.

Comment: Just draw roads as polylines like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56736602/6950238).

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko thanks! polyline is just a line in the map right? If I want to use direction API polyline doesn't count as a road right?

Comment: Yes, you're totally right.